# Python. Сравнение кортежей

Tags: python

Есть реализация собственного компаратора, но необходимо его привести к сравниванию двух кортежей, а не каждого элемента. (Изучаю python, это требование ревьюера).

```py
def is_greater(first_el: int, second_el: int):
    if first_el[1] > second_el[1]:
        return True
    if first_el[1] < second_el[1]:
        return False
    if first_el[2] < second_el[2]:
        return True
    if first_el[2] > second_el[2]:
        return False
    if first_el[0] < second_el[0]:
        return True
    if first_el[0] > second_el[0]:
        return False
    return False
```

Т.к. знаки сравнения у индекса первого элемента отличаются привел эти элементы к отрицательному значению.

Получилось как-то так:

```py
def is_greater(first_el: int, second_el: int):
    if (first_el[1] * -1, first_el[2], first_el[0]) < \
            (second_el[1] * -1, second_el[2], second_el[0]):
        return True
    if (first_el[1] * -1, first_el[2], first_el[0]) > \
            (second_el[1] * -1, second_el[2], second_el[0]):
        return False
    return False
```

Возможно ли как-то его оптимизировать? Потому что после такой реализации у меня алгоритм не проходит тест по времени. Хотя с первым вариантом проходил нормально.

Answer (score 2):

```
def is_greater2(a, b):
    return (b[1],) + a[2::-2] < (a[1],) + b[2::-2]
```

И сравнение реализаций

```
for row in itertools.product([False, True], repeat=6):
    assert is_greater(row[:3], row[3:]) == is_greater2(row[:3], row[3:])
```

Comment: Спасибо. Вариант рабочий.